# Fitting Data w/ Curve Fit Then Find Out if Data is above / below curve fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, exponential

I generated an exponential curve fit for the proxy data below. After fitting the model to the data, I need to determine if another sample `second sample`, row by row, is above or below the fit line. Where I am struggling is how to determine if the `second sample` data is above or below the fit line.

```
#Sample Data for generating the exponential curve fit model
ys = np.array([40951088., 35375058., 22160211., 21306439., 20980581., 15379697.,
       10308974., 16793804.,  6867746.,  5952455.,  4505347.,  4768728.,
        5254116.,  2183644.,  3350415.,  1992107.,  1449918.,   985307.,
        2804293.,  2515258.,   884647.,   251409.,   901582.])

xs = np.array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,
        5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ,  7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5, 10. , 10.5,
       11.])

def monoExp(x, m, t, b):
    return m * np.exp(-t * x) + b

# perform the fit
p0 = (2000, .1, 50) #approximate values
params, cv = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(monoExp, xs, ys, p0, maxfev=5000)
m, t, b = params
sampleRate = 20_000 # Hz
tauSec = (1 / t) / sampleRate

# determine quality of the fit
squaredDiffs = np.square(ys - monoExp(xs, m, t, b))
squaredDiffsFromMean = np.square(ys - np.mean(ys))
rSquared = 1 - np.sum(squaredDiffs) / np.sum(squaredDiffsFromMean)
print(f"R² = {rSquared}")

# plot the results
plt.plot(xs, ys, '.', label="data")
plt.plot(xs, monoExp(xs, m, t, b), '--', label="fitted")
plt.title("Fitted Exponential Curve")

# inspect the parameters
print(f"Y = {m} * e^(-{t} * x) + {b}")
print(f"Tau = {tauSec * 1e6} µs")
```

Here are the results from the code snippet above.

[image]

Now I want to determine whether or not the data from the `second sample` fits above or below the curve used for the first sample. Both `ys` and the `second sample` use `xs` as a sort of index (range from 0 to 11 with 0.5 steps).

```
second_ys = np.array([17623610, 32724312,   918384,   749818,   910372])
second_xs = np.array([0, 0, 0.5, 0, 11.5])
```

I cannot enter `second_ys[0:1]` into the forumla, because the answer is the error term:

```
x1 = 17623610 #second_ys[0:1]
39960941.909692936 * np.exp(-0.4000309715410416 * x1) + 421846.9906738758
>>> 421846.9906738758
```

I am not sure how to determine if values along `second_ys` fall above or below the line.

When I plug the params back into the equation to see if the values are above or below the visually represented curve, it returns all of the same values:

```
monoExp(ys, params[0], params[1], params[2])
>>> array([421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388,
       421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388,
       421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388,
       421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388,
       421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388,
       421846.99067388, 421846.99067388, 421846.99067388])
```

Comment: Inserting the x-values with the fitted parameters should give the fitted line. Then you can just (ys-fitted) and where the result array is > 0 then over the line and where the result array < 0, under the line?

Comment: @NathanFurnal can yo demonstrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have the fitted curve you can replace use the `xs` to determine the origin of the error vector ending in ys

The curve is `monoExp(xs, m, t, b)` accordingly to your plotting code, so you can get the error as follows.

```py
err = ys - monoExp(xs, m, t, b)
plt.stem(xs, err)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bob, this doesnt work because `second_ys` does not have the same size index has `xs`

Comment: And don't you have a `secodn_xs`? If you have you use `second_ys - monoExp(second_xs, m, t,b)`. If xs is not defined the error is given `max(b - second_ys, 0)`, because for any `y > b` (and read t) you can find a `x` that will give `monoExp(x, m, t, b)` that give error zero.